# Is there a way to get assembly level attributes from referenced assemblies using the Compilation object in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I need to get a couple of assembly level attributes within referenced assemblies of a project. The Compilation object has a list of ExternalReferences but the objects in the list don't carry a lot of information about the referenced assemblies. I need a way to get assembly level attributes from the referenced assemblies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a compilation you can get the IAssemblySymbol for each of the extern references.

```cs
var assemblySymbol = (IAssemblySymbol)compilation.GetAssemblyOrModuleSymbol(externalAssemblyRef);
```

Then given an IAssemblySymbol, you can get the assembly level attributes using the GetAttributes() method.

```cs
var assemblyAttributes = assemblySymbol.GetAttributes();
```